# PHP.exe now shows zero bytes (wamp)

Tags: php, wampserver

Today after updates in windows, my php.exe file now shows 0 bytes.

This is not a windows file and don't think a restore will help.

Do not want to reinstall wamp as have lots of settings.

Cant find version 5.4.3 executable file. Have downloaded many of these, however it does not contain php.exe, (probably without installing it).

Has anyone got a version of php.exe that came with wampserver 5.4.3 (32 bit).
I tried 5.4.23.0, and it didnt work!

Can I install just wamp php, without losing any settings.......

Answer (score 0):

this is problem in installation of php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Answer (score 0):

You could install same Wamp Server to a different directory and then copy over php.exe file. This way you would not lose any settings.

Comment: I did install in folder wamp2, and used the php.exe and it worked, but now my listen on port 80 which I changed to port 3700 does not take effect. Meaning that the settings are being read from wamp2 even when I run wamp.exe from the wamp folder?

Comment: Is it possible that your new install is running instead of the old one?

Comment: In windows uninstall files there is only one wampserver. I would think even calling the new one somewhere there is a setting showing the latest install of this. Just trying to rename folders.....that may work

Comment: I am not sure, it might be that the installer you ran overwrite the original services. I try to copy all your files (besides corrupted php folder with 0 size php.exe) to new install instead and try to restart the services.

Comment: Taking a complete backup now....Uninstall and then reinstall......so for all reading....wamp does not like running with two installs, seems like the only way is to make backups of the wamp folder if you are doing any critical work. (bearing in mind its 16gb on my computer with files!)

Comment: FWIW, when I've had both WAMP and a vanilla AMP stack on my machine, WAMP likes to pull the first php.ini file it finds (which is never the  right one). Try renaming the new php.ini to something else so WAMP doesn't find it - would be worth checking it isn't doing this for other config files as well (httpd.conf?)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed WAMPServer again into `\wamp2` as you say you did, then Apache PHP and MySQL will now be running from the new folder.

I suggest you copy what you want from the wamp2 folder to the \wamp folder and then do this to get Apache/PHP/MySQL running again from your old \wamp\ folder.

Using the Wampmanager icon in the system tray do this:

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Remove Service
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Remove Service
```

Now exit wampmanager.

```
right click wampmanager -> Exit
```

Now run the wampmanager from the \wamp folder and reinstall the Apache (wampapache) and MySQL(wampmysql) services from that folder like this :_

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
```

Now rename your \wamp2 folder and check everything still works, maybe a reboot and check wamp will still start and that you see all your databases again in phpmyadmin.
If all is ok, you can delete your \wamp2 folder.